# Verifying three equivalent conditions for a ring to be Noetherian

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, proof-verification, noetherian

Let $A$ be a commutative ring with identity. Then, the following are equivalent:

- Every set of ideals of $A$ has a maximal element;
- Every ascending chain of ideals in $A$ is stationary;
- Every ideal in $A$ is finitely generated.

I'd like my proof to be checked:

(1) $\Rightarrow$ (2): If $(J_i)_{i\in \mathbb{I}}$ is a chain of ideals in $A$ then $\{J_i: i \in \mathbb{I}\}$ has a maximal element $J_k$ and therefore is stationary.

(2) $\Rightarrow$ (3): Let $J$ be an ideal of a ring $A$. If $a \in J$, let $I_a = (a)$. If $I_a=J$ then $J$ is finitely generated. Otherwise, let  $b \in J \setminus I_a$ and let $I_b = I_a + (b)$. Notice that $I_a \subset I_b \subset J$. Following by induction we have an ascending chain of ideals  $(J_i)_{i \in I}$ (for some indexing family $I$), each one finitely generated and by hypothesis this chain is stationary. On the other hand, by construction $\bigcup_{i\in I} J_i = J$, therefore $J = J_k$ is finitely generated.

(3) $\Rightarrow$ (1): Let $X$ be a set of ideals which has no maximal element. Extract from this set an ascending chain $C$ of ideals that is not stationary. Now, as $C$ is a chain, $\cup C$ is an ideal. Because it is finitely generated, there is an $I \in C$ that contains all of its generators and thus $C$ is stationary. Absurd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, your proof is correct!

Some minor comments:

1. In (1) $\Rightarrow$ (2), I'd like to see an argument for why $\{ J_i : i \in \Bbb{I} \}$ having a maximal element $J_k$ implies that the chain $(J_i)_{i \in \Bbb{I}}$ is stationary. This step is not any more difficult than the others, so it warrants equal attention.
2. In (3) $\Rightarrow$ (1), I'd like to see how exactly one can extract from the set $X$ an ascending chain of ideals that is not stationary. Again, it's not particularly difficult, but at least one line of explanation is warranted, in my opinion.